# How do I perform two Tweens in a row affecting the same attribute in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I'm working on an animation using Kinetic.js that requires something to be scaled and then almost "unscaled" immediately after. I saw almost because the second scale is supposed to be slightly different than the original scale value, so I can't actually use `this.reverse()`. I tried to make a second Tween that is called during the `onFinish` function of the first, but I can't seem to manipulate the scale in both of them. Here is the code I am trying:

```
var waveScaleAnimation=new Kinetic.Tween({
        node:waves,
        scaleY:newWaveScale,
        duration:waveScaleDuration,
        onFinish:function(){
            reverseWaveScaleAnimation.play();
        }
    });
    var reverseWaveScaleAnimation=new Kinetic.Tween({
        node:waves,
        scaleY:1,
        duration:waveScaleDuration
    });
```

The really weird thing is the `reverseWaveScaleAnimation` tween isn't the one that doesn't work - if I leave it how it is now, the `scale` from the `waveScaleAnimation` is ignored (so `waves` just stays its original size for the duration of `waveScaleAnimation` and then gets Y-scaled to 1 during `reverseWaveScaleAnimation`. If I take the `scaleY` out of `reverseWaveScaleAnimation`, and replace it with another attribute (let's say `opacity`), the two Tweens work correctly (the `scaleY` of `waves` is changed during `waveScaleAnimation` and its opacity is changed during `reverseWaveScaleAnimation`. How can I get both animations to change the `scaleY` to its corresponding value at during each tween?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for me was to instantiate the tween inside the `onFinish` function:

```
var waveScaleAnimation = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node:waves,
  scaleY:newWaveScale,
  duration:waveScaleDuration,
  onFinish: function () {
    var reverseWaveScaleAnimation = new Kinetic.Tween({
      node:waves,
      scaleY: 1,
      duration:waveScaleDuration,
    });
    reverseWaveScaleAnimation.play();
  }
});
```

See my example here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/projeqht/RzaXR/)

An explanation for this could be that the original node is returning to it's original state before executing the `reverseWaveScaleAnimation` tween possibly because when you instantiate `reverseWaveScaleAnimation` outside, it expects the node in its original state. But if you instantiate the tween inside the `onFinish` function, then the tween expects the node at the state that it is in when the `waveScaleAnimation` tween is finished.

Hopefully that makes sense as my explanation isn't very detailed, perhaps someone else might be able to provide more details about tweens as I don't use them often.

**EDIT:** Actually, that explains the scenario where you switch from tweening `scaleY` to `opacity`. I'm assuming that originally your node will start at `1.0 opacity` but when you tween it towards say `0.0 opacity`, the node originally started at `1.0 opacity` so there's no issues for the tween to start back at `1.0 opacity`  and tween towards `0.0 opacity`. Thus, it **seemed** like the tween was working as intended `onFinish`, but really, it was doing the same as when you were tweening `scaleY`.

Comment: That makes complete sense! I actually just came to the same conclusion so I came back to update my question, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Nice! Glad you figured it out :D

Comment: I still couldn't figure out why it was happening, though, so thank you for clarifying!